# Which of the following statements is (are) true, for three matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A, B, C$ be three matrices such that $AB = C$. 
Which of the following statements is (are) true?

1. the columns in $C^T$ are linear combinations of the columns in $B^T$
2. the columns in $C$ are linear combinations of the columns in $A^T$
3. the columns in $C$ are linear combinations of the columns in $B$
4. the columns in $C^T$ are linear combinations of the columns in $A^T$

**My answer:**
I guess that the only option that is correct is 3 which means that The columns in C are linear combinations of the columns in B. Am I right or could someone please help me to decide of which of these that are correct?

Comment: In fact, the correct answer is 1

Comment: Remark: You can rule out the wrong options by trying a simple example where $A$ is $2 \times 4$, $B$ is $4 \times 3$, and $C$ is $2 \times 3$. The columns of $A$, $A^T$, $B$, $B^T$, $C$, and $C^T$ have dimension $2$, $4$, $4$, $3$, $2$, and $3$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The matrix $AB$ has columns that are the linear combinations of the columns of $A$, and rows that are the linear combinations of the rows of $B$.  To see that this is true, note that each column of $AB$ has the form
$$
\pmatrix{C_1 & C_2 & C_3} \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2\\b_3} = b_1 C_1 + b_2 C_2 + b_3 C_3
$$
where $C_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$.  Similarly, each row of $AB$ as the form
$$
\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 & a_3} \pmatrix{R_1\\R_2\\R_3} = a_1 R_1 + a_2 R_2 + a_3 R_3
$$
where $R_i$ is the $i$th row of $B$.

Of course, the columns of $A^T$ are simply the rows of $A$.